# Get window handle of last activated window

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am developing an application that sits in the system tray and can perform actions on the active window. But when the icon in the system tray is clicked, `GetForegroundWindow()` returns the taskbar. I need to get the window that was active before the taskbar was.

I've tried enumerating the desktop window with `EnumWindows` and `GetWindow`, but this is often turning up desktop gadgets and other top items that where not active last. Is it even possible, or the information completely lost when the window is deactivated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to get that info is by installing a system wide hook ([SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx)) on `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and capturing all `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`. This will even enable you to track the full history of which window was active when.

Comment: This works really well. However, I have an issue about some applications being unaffected because they are 64-bit (or 32-bit if I compile for 64-bit). Any ideas?

Comment: I can hook with both a 32-bit and a 64-bit DLL and use some sort of interprocess communication between the two but it is looking very messy.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's a clean way of doing it, so two DLLs and some IPC is ASFAIK the only way to go.

Comment: Alternative to WH_CALLWNDPROC, use WH_CBT instead, and look for HCBT_ACTIVATE

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetTopWindow(NULL)` and `GetNextWindow(hwnd)` to list all windows sorted by Z.
Next just skip all windows that belong to `exeplorer.exe` and first found window will be most top user window.

The only case when I notice a problem is when somebody have window with option "Alwyas On Top". For example Winamp have option like this. But that's rather unusual case.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h> /// for CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()
#include <assert.h>

HWND getLastActiveWindow(){
    /// find process ID of first explorer.exe
    /// normaly there will be only 1 anyway.
    static DWORD explorerProcessId= 0; /// we can cache it, since it shoudn't change
    if(!explorerProcessId){
        PROCESSENTRY32 entry= {0};
        entry.dwSize= sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        HANDLE snap= CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0 );
        if( Process32First( snap, &entry ) ){
            do{
                if( strcmp(entry.szExeFile,"explorer.exe")==0 ){ /// we are searching for explorer.exe
                    explorerProcessId= entry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            }while( Process32Next(snap,&entry) );
        }
        CloseHandle( snap );
    }
    assert( explorerProcessId );

    /// list of all windows sorted in Z-Order
    {
        HWND hwnd= GetTopWindow( NULL ); /// get window with highest Z
        while( hwnd ){
            if( IsWindowVisible(hwnd) ){ /// we care only about visible windows
                DWORD procId;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwnd, &procId ); /// get process ID of hwnd
                if( procId != explorerProcessId ){ /// we don't care about window owned by explorer.exe
                    return hwnd; /// return top most window
                }
            }
            hwnd= GetNextWindow( hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT ); /// get next windows in Z order
        }
    }

    /// No window found.
    /// It may happen if there are no window opened, so handle that case somehow, depending on your application
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this. The z-order has one big flaw mentioned in the documentation: `All topmost windows appear in the z-order before any non-topmost windows.` The catch is: a window can be topmost, while it's hidden from the user by simply being placed outside the monitor area. Now, why someone would want to create a topmost window, and then hide it in such a nasty way? Why don't you ask Inkscape developers? I've just discovered that no matter what I do, Inkscape is always at the top of the z-order because it has some windows flagged as topmost, but moved outside the visible area.